# Error message: The Bundle ID you entered has already been used

Tags: ios, itunes

I am trying to publish an iPhone app; it is not the first, I already published others in the past. So I entered the required info in the first and second form, and then filled in the big third form, the one where you also upload icon and screenshots. Well, I pressed the "Save" button before uploading the screenshots, because I noticed that I had no retina-4 screenshot available, and had to produced it first.

Why did I press "Save"? Well, I just wanted to make sure all the info I had entered wouldn't get lost.

Reasonably, I got an error message regarding the missing screenshots.

After a while I uploaded the screenshots, but when trying to save again, I got a generic error, something like "There has been an error, contact support". Maybe my session had expired in the meantime???

OK, so I press "Cancel". I return to the initial screen, where my apps are listed. No sign of the new one, so I guess I have to re-enter everything again.

The bad surprise is that when I fill in the first form I get an error message:

```
The Bundle ID you entered has already been used
```

I guess I will have to choose a different bundle ID... sounds crazy, just can't believe it... any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had faced the same problem at the time of my last app uploading. And as i was not having time to go through the Error, I simply changed the bundle id with new one. And it get done. I will suggest you to create new one and go with that.

Comment: In fact this is what I did. It looks like when a bundle ID has been entered, it can't be re-used, even if the "new app" procedure has failed and must be repeated. Thank you.

Comment: I really faced it as strange behaviour , Apple should must find some alternative to this, Even i have sent the mail to support with step by step scenario, regarding the same issue, Lets see what they says. It irritates at the time of working. Any ways Always Welcome.

Comment: Apple needs to find an alternative to everything they're doing.  This process is f***ing insane

Comment: Almost 5 years have passed... still the same issue 

Comment: I also havent the same issue. Anyone know how to check where is the bundle ID?

Answer (score 0):

The message is trying to tell that the bundle ID already exist in apple there. Because it must be unique, thus no body can create a new one.

Why you saw this is probably the account you using in your mac book or xcode no longer have access to this bundle. Try login to apple developer account to check whether you still able to see this app or not. And try to check with application admin to check is it your account being remove for this bundle access.