# Having problems with Submitting app to appstore

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

Im having trouble submitting my application to Appstore. After i tried archiving my application it said that the bundle id was wrong. And now i think im changing it to the correct one but i get this error:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/c8vmlcj6z2ty1xl/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-29%20at%2021.28.09.png?dl=0

**The bundle ID you entered has already been used**

So first question is why do i get that error?

Second question is. Is my bundle ID correct now? This is the image of my bundle ID in Xcode:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b4u2otyi1ogf2n4/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-29%20at%2021.31.55.png?dl=0

They match now right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you replace a rejected app store binary if the version number should not be incremented?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29064369/how-do-you-replace-a-rejected-app-store-binary-if-the-version-number-should-not)

Comment: Why would you post same thing twice. Also my error message had nothing to do with the build verison? @LyndseyScott

Comment: One post was the link to an answer the other post was auto generated when I selected that this was a possible duplicate. And yes, I see now that you're referring to a different error. This question instead seems to be a duplicate of this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/22112991/2274694 and this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/9742576/2274694 and this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/14399411/2274694

Comment: Ok thank you for that now i know i have to change the bundle ID. I just have a question. The first image that i posted,  is that correct the way it should look to match the bundle id in Xcode?. So im guessing all i need to do is change the bundle ID in Xcode and then just write something else in the suffix if im not wrong? @LyndseyScott

Comment: On second thought, I need to create a new app id that has the same bundle id as the one im going to change it to right?

Answer (score 0):

For other people coming here that wonders what to do, follow these simple steps it worked for me.

1) Go to Xcode click on your project and then change your Bundle Identifier. Mine was com.Timocin.GBGLiveScore i changed it to com.Timocinn.GBGLiveScore

2) Create a new app id and provisioning profile to the new Bundle ID if you already had not done it.

3) Submit the app and hope for the best :D